# Close blocking connections

Tags: c#, port

I'm having a problem.  When I try to start my `TcpListener` I am constantly getting an error telling me the port is already in use.  Is there any way for me to close that connection programmatically? I have had this problem many times before, with web servers, game servers, etc.

It's not the problem that my own program is keeping the port open, its some other program. Lets say I want to distribute my program, there will always be a few users who have a program like Skype listening on that port.  How can I close that connection without knowing what program is listening on it, so that I can use that port myself?

Comment: You should just use a different port if another application is using the one you planned to use, rather than trying to kill their connection just because you want to use the port.

Comment: Tomorrow: [“I have an application that uses `TcpListener` and some other application keeps closing my connection. How can I prevent it from doing that?”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/17/10257351.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can test the availability of the port before trying to connect:

```
 int port = 1048; //<--- This is your value
 bool isAvailable = true;

 IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
 TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

 foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
 {
   if (tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port==port)
   {
     isAvailable = false;
     break;
   }
 }

if(isAvailable == true)
{
// connect.
}
```

Comment: I know how to check for open ports, but its just that i can't use any other ports than 80 in my case, so i need to find a way to kill the process that is locking up port 80

Comment: @user2073973 Why can't you use a port other than 80?  Unless you're creating your own webserver you really shouldn't be using port 80; convention dictates it's specifically for serving up HTTP content.  If you are creating your own webserver then you shouldn't be running other applications on the machine using that port.